# WPF Designer Adorner: Updating XAML attribute values

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, adorner

Ok i'll try to keep it simple:

I made a custom table control which in design mode will paint 2 lines which i can drag to control the header and row size. When i change the adorner position i also update the properties of the control.

the properties are declared like so:

```
public double? HeaderHeight { get; set; }
public double? RowHeight { get; set; }
```

But i don't see these changes reflected in the XAML no matter how much i drag the adorner around.

```
<table1:ReflectiveTable HeaderHeight="20" RowHeight="10" />
```

[image: Screenshot]

Events from the adorner is handled like so:

```
private void AdornerHeaderDrag(Adorner.Helpers.IRectangleDimensions obj) {
    HeaderHeight = obj.Y + obj.Height / 2;
}

private void AdornerRowsDrag(Adorner.Helpers.IRectangleDimensions obj){
    RowHeight = obj.Y + obj.Height / 2;
    if (ExcludeHeader == false)
        RowHeight -= HeaderHeight;
}
```

Comment: These properties need to be [Dependency Properties](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140620/WPF-Tutorial-Dependency-Property).

Comment: Declaring them as dependency properties yields the same result.

Comment: The custom control is located in a different project which is referenced by my WPF UI project which just contains a single window which in XAML has the control referenced.

Comment: show code where you are updating your properties

Comment: added the event handlers to my question.